# What to do after Stratified K-fold?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I have used the [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) to cross validate my training data set. The model has achieved an accuracy of 75% which I have found acceptable.

Should I just continue and implement my model onto the test set:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Or should I be doing something else to enforce the Stratified k-fold to obtain a new test set?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: I cannot understand if you want to have an hint a) in terms of Data Science process or b) from the coding point of view. In the case of a) probably this is not the right place to ask, in case of b) try to describe better want you want to achieve.